# PHP ini file_get_contents external url

Tags: php, url, external, file-get-contents, ini

I use following PHP function:

`file_get_contents('http://example.com');`

Whenever I do this on a certain server, the result is empty. When I do it anywhere else, the result is whatever the page's content may be. When I however, on the server where the result is empty, use the function locally - without accessing an external URL (`file_get_contents('../simple/internal/path.html');`), it *does* work.

Now, I am pretty sure it has something to do with a certain php.ini configuration. What I am however not sure about is, *which* one. Please help.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

The setting you are looking for is [`allow_url_fopen`](http://php.net/manual/en/filesystem.configuration.php).

You have two ways of getting around it without changing php.ini, one of them is to use [`fsockopen()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fsockopen.php), and the other is to use [cURL](http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php).

I recommend using cURL over `file_get_contents()` anyways, since it was built for this.

Comment: This is not entirely correct. You can use cURL with `file_get_contents()` with the configure option `--with-curlwrappers`.

Comment: @Artefacto I don't understand. Please elaborate.

Comment: If you compile the curl extension with `--with-curlwrappers`, curl will be used to make a HTTP request whenever you do `file_get_contents("http://example.com/stuff")`. My point was that curl and `file_get_contents` are not orthogonal, it's not "use one or the other".

Answer (score 51):

Complementing Aillyn's answer, you could use a function like the one below to mimic the behavior of file_get_contents:

```
function get_content($URL){
      $ch = curl_init();
      curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
      curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $URL);
      $data = curl_exec($ch);
      curl_close($ch);
      return $data;
}

echo get_content('http://example.com');
```

Comment: this is awesome.. I just replaced aall of my "filt_get_content($url).... functions to  "get_content($url) and placed your function the top of file.. and wow.. all functions run so smoothly..

Answer (score 5):

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://www.your_external_website.com");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
$result = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```

is best for http url,
But how to open https url help me

Answer (score 4):

The is related to the ini configuration setting [`allow_url_fopen`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/filesystem.configuration.php#ini.allow-url-fopen).

You should be aware that enable that option may make some bugs in your code exploitable.

For instance, this failure to validate input may turn into a full-fledged remote code execution vulnerability:

```
copy($_GET["file"], ".");
```

Answer (score 3):

The answers provided above solve the problem but don't explain the strange behaviour the OP described. This explanation should help anyone testing communication between sites in a development environment where these sites all reside on the same host (and the same virtualhost; I'm working with apache 2.4 and php7.0).

There's a subtlety with `file_get_contents()` I came across that is absolutely relevant here but unaddressed (probably because it's either barely documented or not documented from what I can tell or is documented in an obscure php security model whitepaper I can't find).

With `allow_url_fopen` set to `Off` in all relevant contexts (e.g. `/etc/php/7.0/apache2/php.ini`, `/etc/php/7.0/fpm/php.ini`, etc...) and `allow_url_fopen` set to `On` in the command line context (i.e. `/etc/php/7.0/cli/php.ini`), calls to `file_get_contents()` for a local resource will be allowed and no warning will be logged such as:

```
file_get_contents('php://input');
```

or

```
// Path outside document root that webserver user agent has permission to read. e.g. for an apache2 webserver this user agent might be www-data so a file at /etc/php/7.0/filetoaccess would be successfully read if www-data had permission to read this file
file_get_contents('<file path to file on local machine user agent can access>');
```

or

```
// Relative path in same document root
file_get_contents('data/filename.dat')
```

To conclude, the restriction `allow_url_fopen = Off` is analogous to an `iptables` rule in the `OUTPUT` chain, where the restriction is only applied when an attempt to "exit the system" or "change contexts" is made.

N.B. `allow_url_fopen` set to `On` in the command line context (i.e. `/etc/php/7.0/cli/php.ini`) is what I had on my system but I suspect it would have no bearing on the explanation I provided even if it were set to `Off` unless of course you're testing by running your scripts from the command line itself. I did not test the behaviour with `allow_url_fopen` set to `Off` in the command line context.

Answer (score 1):

This will also give external links an absolute path without having to use php.ini

```
<?php
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://www.your_external_website.com");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
$result = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
$result = preg_replace("#(<\s*a\s+[^>]*href\s*=\s*[\"'])(?!http)([^\"'>]+)([\"'>]+)#",'$1http://www.your_external_website.com/$2$3', $result);
echo $result
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Enable allow_url_fopen From cPanel Or WHM in PHP INI Section

Answer (score 0):

Add:

```
allow_url_fopen=1
```

in your `php.ini` file. If you are using shared hosting, create one first.

Comment: You may also add some background information so people know why and not only what to do.