# How can I parse JSON data from an API call?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, json

Here's what I have at the moment:

```
<?php
    $string = file_get_contents("http://api.steampowered.com/ISteamUser/GetPlayerSummaries/v0002/?key=##################################&steamids=76561198040884950");
    $json=json_decode($string);
?>

<script type="text/javascript">
        alert("<?php echo $json; ?>");
</script>
```

All I'm trying to do at this stage is receive the JSON information. I'm quite new to jQuery and PHP so not sure where I'm going wrong.

Comment: Yes, you are doing correct `json_decode`. but what you want exactly ?

Comment: Publicly posting your Steam API key is a violation of the Steam API terms of use. You should edit your post to remove it ASAP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By using `json_decode` you're converting the JSON from a string (which can be universally understood and parsed) to a PHP object or array, which will not print out the way you wish. You should avoid converting it and simply do something like this:

```
<?php
    $string = file_get_contents("http://api.steampowered.com/ISteamUser/GetPlayerSummaries/v0002/?key=...&steamids=76561198040884950");
?>

<script type="text/javascript">
        var json = <?php echo $string; ?>;
        // do things with the JSON; parse it into an object, etc
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

check this out http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseJSON/ ,something like this

```
var obj = jQuery.parseJSON('{"name":"John"}');
alert( obj.name === "John" );
```

Answer (score 1):

When using [json_decode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) through PHP, your output will be returned in an array;

When returning json information from external files to jquery scripts you must ensure to use the proper syntax. [Codex](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/)

Answer (score 1):

Secondly I'm not sure if you know, but in using file_get_contents, you need your php.ini file to have the following flag:

> allow_url_fopen = 1

If you don't want to, there are alternatives:
[Check it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3488425/php-ini-file-get-contents-external-url)

Answer (score 1):

Try using `<?php print_r($json); ?>` instead of `echo`.  It's doing what you want it to.  `echo` just isn't any good at handling arrays.