# Timezone detection from Clients' IP Address

Tags: php, api, datetime, timezone

is there a way to detect to IP Address of my client then use this to track his timezone..
iam currently using this block of code together with an API:

```
    function getIpAddress() {
    return (empty($_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'])?(empty($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'])?$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']:$_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR']):$_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP']);
}

    ini_set("allow_url_fopen",1);
    $getfunc= 'getIpAddress';
    $getfunc= 'getIpAddress'; 
    $json   = file_get_contents('http://smart-ip.net/geoip-json/'.$ip);
    $ipData = json_decode( $json, true);
    $ipadd   = $ipData['host'];
    $geotz  = $ipData['timezone'];
    $geotzd = 'Passed';
    $cntry  = $ipData['countryName'];
```

the $ip returns 122.54.230.162. but still sayin that my problem is

```
    Message: Undefined index: timezone
```

testing it on the server will show this error while it is okay on local..
i need help

best regards..

Comment: What's `$json` value ? Can you log it ?

Comment: You should take a look the following link. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3488425/php-ini-file-get-contents-external-url

Comment: Psst, you're getting the IP address of the result of `hostname`, which may well result in a local or private IP address range.  Perhaps you should put a real IP address there for stesting instead.

Comment: actually i have change $ip to

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are various ways of guessing the timezone. Using a service like in your question is one, although that code looks to me like it gets the timezone of the local computer, but I could be wrong. In any case, it doesn't seem reliable.

Another way is the [jstimezonedetect](https://bitbucket.org/pellepim/jstimezonedetect) javascript library.