# file_get_contents() connection refused to local file url

Tags: php, apache, file-get-contents

For some reason file_get_contents isn't allowing me to get files which are on the same server.

This is the error I'm getting:

```
file_get_contents(http://www.my-url.com/image.jpg): failed to open stream: Connection refused
```

I know I can use the system path to get files but in this case I need to be able to test this with the URL.

Comment: Check your php.ini, is the "allow_url_fopen = On".

Comment: If they're on the same server, why don't you use the file-system path?

Comment: the allow_url_fopen is already On, and I can't use the system path because I'm using a WordPress function that needs an URL

Comment: please refer to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3488425/php-ini-file-get-contents-external-url)

Hope this helps.

Comment: If they're on the same server, then DON'T use a full-blown http request. That's massively wasteful. Use the local filesystem path, e.g. `file_get_contents('/home/sites/my-url.com/html/image.jpg')`

Comment: I realize it's wasteful and using a local filesystem path is more effective, I'm just unable to do it in this case.

Also @Vanitas allow_url_fopen is already turned On, and cURL isn't working either.

Answer (score 1):

Even if the file you are opening is on your server if you are using the url rather than the directory mechanism, you will need to set

```
allow_url_fopen = On
```

In you php.ini file.