# json parse from result.php file url

Tags: php, json

i have a php file that return json. here my php file.

http://dev.mediaodd.com/data/testjson.php

if i use writing testjson.json file it will success but if i use .php it will failed.

this is my output script:

```
<?php
// copy file content into a string var

$jsondata = file_get_contents('http://dev.mediaodd.com/data/testjson.php');
$obj = json_decode($jsondata,true);


echo $obj['company'][0]['id'];

?>
```

what did i do wrong?

file_get_contents cant read .php file?

my testjson.php file return same as testjason.json file.

Comment: I just entered that `testjson.php` file and it prints `null`.

Comment: sorry about that. i have fix that. u can click again. please help me.

Comment: It still returns `null`. I believe that while your attached code should work (`file_get_contents`), the content you get from that URL isn't what you're expecting.

Comment: i have fixed that json link.

Comment: can u try click it again?

Comment: ok, if you write `var_dump($jsondata);` right after the `file_get_contents` line - what's the output of that file?

Comment: it will return array from my json file.

Comment: [link](http://dev.mediaodd.com/data/test.php)

Comment: Can you add the output to your question? Another test (that should be that last probably before solving it) - add the same line after the `json_decode` line, what's the output now?

Comment: Probably you missed the double quotes: `echo $obj['"company"'][0]['"id"'];` however this does not make sense. If you are the owner of the JSON source I would remove those unnecessary double quotes around each key.

Comment: u can click the link i provide here http://dev.mediaodd.com/data/test.php this link will return the output

Comment: @TiMESPLiNTER lol. that was the answer! glad you help me! thanks!!!!

Comment: We're not here to have a live chat session to diagnose your problem. Please clearly state within the question itself what it *should* do and what it *does* do and what problem you have with it.

Comment: @deceze why so serious?

Comment: I'm explaining why your question has received a down vote and a close vote and will likely by closed eventually. You should get familiar with the quality standards of Stackoverflow so as to write better questions (and answers) in the future.

Answer (score 0):

**after clarification by OP, the following is not the case**

[`file_get_contents`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php) cannot read from url resource unless this has been setup explicitly in [php.ini configuration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3488425/php-ini-file-get-contents-external-url) (not recommended mostly for security reasons).

So you should **not** use `file_get_contents('http://dev.mediaodd.com/data/testjson.php');` to read an http resource, but instead read from **local php files** only that exist in the (server) disk

Comment: i already allow it before i post this question. so the problem i have is not what u said. can i use 'code'file_get_contents('http://dev.mediaodd.com/data/testjson.php?id=abc'); that have get method?

Comment: It's the other way round, url wrappers are ON by default and you would be explicitly turn them off, answer is not correct.

Comment: @DanFromGermany for most default php configurations used in production, the functionality is OFF

Comment: The last 30 webservers I was on, which I was not admin of, had it ON. The default also is ON. Wrappers are enabled by default, too. I cannot confirm "most" servers have it disabled...

Comment: @DanFromGermany, hmm ok, but you will agree that it is not recommended to leave them ON mainly for security reasons and there are lot of references on the interweb about specificaly php configuration and security mentioning this

Comment: @NikosM. I think you do mistake the configuration for fopen/file_get_contents with `allow_url_include`. That one is disabled by default and presents a big security risk. The other one, `allow_url_fopen` is on by default, it allows you to read feeds and json for example. See http://php.net/manual/en/filesystem.configuration.php