# Unable to access visa.com with file_get_contents

Tags: php, web-scraping

I'm trying to build a simple PHP page that pulls today's EURUSD exchange rate from Visa.com.

The URL is 
http://usa.visa.com/support/consumer/travel-support/exchange-rate-calculator.html/?fromCurr=USD&toCurr=EUR&fee=0&exchangedate=11/23/2015

I want to get today's rate without filling out the form every time.

But when I tried to run `file_get_contents` with this URL (tried with 2 separate servers) I keep getting

> Access Denied
>
> You don't have permission to access
>   "http://usa.visa.com/support/consumer/travel-support/exchange-rate-calculator.html/?"
>   on this server.

Other URLs work fine.

Even http://usa.visa.com does not work.

Comment: They will have it blocked so people can't do exactly what you're trying to do. Services charge to provide live conversion rates. You might want to try https://openexchangerates.org/

Comment: The problem is that Visa's rate is different from the 'official' bank rate. I haven't been able to find it on any other site. What exactly are they blocking? How is the PHP request different from me going though my browser? I am able to skip the form by just changing the date in the URL.

Comment: Could also be a permissions problem, check this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3488425/php-ini-file-get-contents-external-url

All else fails, go to CURL & be sure to set the same useragent as a common browser in the headers. That will convince the receiving server that you're a browser and will return results accordingly.

Comment: I tried CURL; same error.

Comment: Can I go through a proxy server somehow?