# Can I use file_get_contents() on a dynamically generated JSON output?

Tags: php, mysql, json

I'm trying to implement [Tokenize2](https://github.com/zellerda/Tokenize2) on my page.

Part of the code to pull data from a JSON source involves this line:

`$obj = json_decode(file_get_contents('search_list.json'), true);`

I have a `search_list.php` where I pull data from a mySQL database and generate the JSON content. But if I put `search_list.php` into the `file_get_contents()` it doesn't seem to work. Is there a way to get around this? Thanks.

Comment: You would have to make the request to *an HTTP server* where the PHP will actually be executed, e.g. `http://localhost/search_list.php`. But since you're then executing PHP, encoding some result as JSON, output the JSON over HTTP, read the HTTP and decode the JSON to a PHP array..... Just skip all that middleware and directly execute the same PHP code as in `search_list.php`; perhaps you just need to put that logic into a function which you can `include` and call.

Comment: `allow_url_fopen` has to be open on your server - check php settings. Other options offered at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3488425/php-ini-file-get-contents-external-url

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`file_get_contents()` doesn't execute code. It just sucks in some bytes, basically a wrapper around `fopen(); fread(); fclose()`. That's it.

You'd have to `include` your script, e.g.

```
ob_start();
include('yourscript.php');
$json = ob_end_clean();
```

but at that point, you should ask yourself while you're going to all the trouble of including/executing that script, forcing it to generate a JSON string, and tearing that json string apart into a PHP array again. Total and absolute waste of cpu resources.

You should do something better, like:

```
function whatever($output = 'json') {
       ... build data structure
       if ($output == 'json') {
         echo json_encode($data);
       } else 
         return $data;
       }
    }
```

It's already PHP code, you already had all your data in a PHP data structure, so why do the wasteful step of data->json->data?

Comment: Thanks for the advice, I will give this a try. I had some autocomplete code that used my PHP script as a data source and it accepted it fine, that's why I was trying to reuse it. I'll be tweaking the data a little bit so I'll following your latter recommendation.