# PHP to get File content of dynamic generated file

Tags: php

I want to collect the content of a dynamically generated file, and place the content inside an email that will be sent but am unable to return the content.

```
/file/invoice/html/{id}
```

The file its self is a `.htaccess` written file so it is not actually the location or the file its self, i want the content that the you see when viewing in the browser I want to be able to get the contents of it and insert it into an email as content.

The `.htaccess` controls the type of file and format of the file.
the htaccess that i am using for the file is

```
RewriteRule ^file/([^/]+)?$ file.php?file=$1 [QSA]  
RewriteRule ^file/([^/]+)/([^/]+)?$ file.php?file=$1&find=$2 [QSA]  
RewriteRule ^file/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)?$ file.php?file=$1&type=$2&find=$3 [QSA]
```

I have tried

```
file_get_contents('http://domain.com/file/invoice/html/1')
file_get_contents('./file/invoice/html/1')
```

but this does not bring back the content that I can see.
i have worked out that it is the "is user logged in check" that is stopping it but as u can guess i dont want to remove this from the file. is there a way to do this with it still there . this is the bit stopping it but i would prefer not to remove it

```
if (!isset($_SESSION['LOGGED_IN'])){
    die(CLOSE_WINDOW);
}elseif(isset($_SESSION['LOGGED_IN']) && $_SESSION['LOGGED_IN'] != TRUE){
    die(CLOSE_WINDOW);
}
```

What I am doing wrong and how can I solve it?

Comment: if your going to -1 it please say why. the question is correct to the terms of post

Comment: I do not know who downvoted you, but I give my vote to your question. but you might need to reshine your question to be more clear.

Comment: `error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', '1');`

Answer (score 2):

You're attempting to download a remote file using `file_get_contents`. This is essentially the same question here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3488430/901156.

If you truly want to be able to do this, you have to update your PHP config to [`allow_url_fopen`](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/filesystem.configuration.php#ini.allow-url-fopen)

Also, it has been suggested [for security and other reasons] to use cURL instead.