# file_get_contents(): failed to open stream: Permission denied

Tags: php, url, file-upload, permissions

I'm trying to load `image` from `url`.
 Everything works fine in `localhost`.

When I run the code on my webserver it is saying

`Warning: file_get_contents(url): failed to open stream: Permission denied in /home/www/ .../imageup.php on line 64`

I've searched on `google` and tried with many answers from `stackoverflow`.
Everyone is saying to set `proper permission` to the file and folder.

I've set the `permission` for the `php file` and the folder to `777`.

Some answers saying to run some commands but I can't find the console to run that code so I allowed permission manually.

I can understand that there is something with permission but can't figure out.
*(Someone may say this is an duplicate and may be it is, but I am fail to find solution)*

```
$file = file_get_contents($image['src']);
```

Comment: 3 questions. 1) What's the src? 2) What's your webhost root 3) can you use that function on a file that exists in the same folder of your php file.

Comment: 1. `$image['src']` returns an `url`

Comment: so it's like `http://example.org/image.png` If you're getting permission denied on this it means that `allow_url_fopen` is false. see this stackoverflow question, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3488425/php-ini-file-get-contents-external-url. Your webhosting provider doesn't allow this.

Comment: `allow_url_fopen` is allowed on my server

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP ini file\_get\_contents external url](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3488425/php-ini-file-get-contents-external-url)

Answer (score 1):

This is because `images` and `tmp_file_upload` are only writable by `root` user. For upload to work we need to make the owner of those folders same as httpd process owner OR make them globally writable (bad practice).

1.Check apache process owner: `$ps aux | grep httpd`. The first column will be the owner typically it will be `nobody`

2.Change the owner of images and tmp_file_upload to be become `nobody` or whatever the owner you found in step 1.

`$sudo chown nobody /var/www/html/mysite/images/`

`$sudo chown nobody /var/www/html/mysite/tmp_file_upload/`

3.Chmod `images` and `tmp_file_upload` now to be writable by the owner, if needed [Seems you already have this in place]. Mentioned in @Dmitry Teplyakov answer.

`$ sudo chmod -R 0755 /var/www/html/mysite/images/`

`$ sudo chmod -R 0755 /var/www/html/mysite/tmp_file_upload/`

4.For more details why this behavior happend, check the manual http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.upload-tmp-dir , note that it also talking about `open_basedir` directive.

Answer (score -1):

Please go to your project root directory and run following command

```
find . -type d -exec chmod 770 {} \; && find . -type f -exec chmod 660 {} \;
```

I hope It will solve your issue.

Comment: Do I need a console or something to run the code? or in a file as code?