# file_put_contents file not uploading properly (file damaged or corrupted )

Tags: file, laravel-5, laravel-api

I have used following way to store file in public folder through api but file data damazed or corrupted

**1st way:-**

```
$filename="Pqr.pdf";

$resume="http://localhost/project_name/public/datafiles/APPL/Xyz.pdf";  //url link of 1st laravel project

file_put_contents(public_path('datafiles/APPL').'/'.$filename, fopen($resume, 'r'));   //file upload in 2nd laravel project
```

**2nd way:-**

```
$filename="Pqr.pdf";

$resume="http://localhost/project_name/public/datafiles/APPL/Xyz.pdf"; 

file_put_contents(public_path('datafiles/APPL').'/'.$filename,file_get_contents($resume);
```

**3rd way:-**

```
$filename="Pqr.pdf";

$resume="http://localhost/project_name/public/datafiles/APPL/Xyz.pdf"; 

$data=file_get_contents($resume);

file_put_contents(public_path('datafiles/APPL').'/'.$filename,base64_decode($data));
```

Comment: Can  you show the exact error you are getting?

Comment: @PrashantDeshmukh..... I am not getting any error...Infact my file is saving at proper location but not opening properly..

Comment: This might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3488425/php-ini-file-get-contents-external-url

Comment: Do you getting proper data from `file_get_contents();`

Comment: @PrashantDeshmukh.....Thank you....I wast not getting an proper data in file_get_content()..The problem has been solved..Thank you.