# why is geoplugin api doesnt work on online server?

Tags: php

I'm trying to get the IP and location data of my visitors but I'm getting an error.

My Code works on localhost but refer no data but not on my online server
there is the code:

```
<?php
//GET th passed data
$page = $_GET['page'];
//GET VISITOR IP
function get_ip(){
    if(isset($_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'])){
        return $_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'];
    }elseif(isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'])){
        return $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'];
    }
    else{
        return (isset($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']) ? $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] : '');
    }
}
$ip =get_ip();
if($ip){
    $query = unserialize(file_get_contents('http://www.geoplugin.net/php.gp?ip='.$ip));
    if($query){    
        //getting th variabales
        $country = $query['geoplugin_countryName'];
        $countrycode = $query['geoplugin_countryCode'];
        $city = $query['geoplugin_city'];
        $regionname = $query['geoplugin_regionName'];
        $lat =  $query['geoplugin_latitude'];
        $long = $query['geoplugin_longitude'];
        $timezone = $query['geoplugin_timezone'];
        //move the variabales
        echo "<script> window.location.assign('../".$page.".php?IP=".$ip."&country=".$country."&countrycode=".$countrycode."&city=".$city."&latitude=".$lat."&longtitude=".$long."&timez=".$timezone."&regionName=".$regionname."&gettingdata= success');</script>";
    }else{
        echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('حدث خطأ ما والرجاء المحاولة في ما بعد')</script>";
        echo "<script> window.location.assign('../index.php?getting data = failed');</script>"; 
    } 
}else{
        echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('حدث خطأ يرجى المحاولة في ما بعد')</script>";
        echo "<script> window.location.assign('../index.php?getting IP= failed');</script>"; 
}
?>
```

Comment: Do you have any error?

Comment: What do you mean by "not working"? Do you get any errors? Add [error reporting](//php.net/manual/function.error-reporting.php) at the top of your file(s): `ini_set("display_errors", 1); error_reporting(E_ALL);` and tell us what you get.

Comment: Instead of using `file_get_contents`, you should switch to cURL. It's a lot more configurable, and easier to get error messages out of. And it works when `file_get_contents` cannot get URLs.

Comment: @Machavity , it give this: file_get_contents(): http:// wrapper is disabled in the server configuration by allow_url_fopen=0 in /home/menuelis/public_html/php/data.php on line 18

Comment: @aynber , which function shoud be used is it curl_getinfo, thank u

Comment: No, that is just one function of the [cURL library](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php)

Comment: @aynber excuse me, but i dont know very much about curl so when i replace file_get_contents() what should I put instead of it

Comment: thank you guys, i have changed allow_url_fopen setting and its worked

Answer (score 0):

Most likely your live server doesn't allow `file_get_contents` to load files via HTTP, which is a security measure.

You should look into your `php.ini`to find the value set for [allow_url_fopen](http://php.net/manual/en/filesystem.configuration.php)

A similar problem [was solved here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3488430/6813537)

Comment: thank u ,i search in youtube of how to change allow_url_fopen but i cant find php_inic in my cpanel

Comment: An alternative method would be `echo ini_get('allow_url_fopen')` in one of your PHP files, or you create a file with `<?php phpinfo(); `, but please make sure to delete it after you've viewed it, as it will expose all your settings

Comment: Also, like the comments suggested, you should probably switch to cURL