# JSON sends funny result

Tags: php, json

I am trying to read this JSON file, which I checked is valid
https://www.webminepool.com/api/PK_MgGG3Z8joogwr28PmkE9i/wmc_rate/1000

Here is my code:

```
//normally the rate is changed via PHP
$checkbtc = "https://www.webminepool.com/api/PK_MgGG3Z8joogwr28PmkE9i/wmc_rate/1000";

$json = file_get_contents($checkbtc);
$json = utf8_encode($json);
$json_data = json_decode($json,true);
print('<br>...'.$json_data.'...<br>');
var_dump($json_data);
```

The file in my browser sends :

```
{"success":true,"satoshi":"26.936"}
```

which seems correct

The result when I execute php is :

```
<br>......<br>
```

So where am I wrong ???
Thanks

file()
file_get_contents()
with or without utf8_encode
STUCK

Comment: Probably utf8_encode. actually you do not required it here. try to remove it and check once.

Comment: Have you tried to cURL it instead of file_get_content? Seems like the host needs some user agents or content type

Comment: Did you output/debug `$json` to see what it contains?

Comment: The site itself seems to have an SSL protocol error (at least if you visit it in Chrome), so maybe PHP can't even download the data. Have you actually tried to debug that? "Stuck" isn't really a useful description of your efforts so far. Given that it's inaccessible it's  unclear how you have actually been able to check that the JSON is valid, as you mentioned?

Comment: Please have a look here it is already discussed. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3488425/php-ini-file-get-contents-external-url

Comment: I have also parsed other multi dimensionnal arrays from this site, that work fine. But this one gives me headache. Also tried with utfencode and without utfencode

Comment: Hi again. I tried with the example of curl and I am stuck with this file. Others work properly but this one doesnt...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like the endpoint is doing some checks to validate your user-agent, you better to use cURL with it.

```
$checkbtc = "https://www.webminepool.com/api/PK_MgGG3Z8joogwr28PmkE9i/wmc_rate/1000";

$cu = curl_init($checkbtc);
curl_setopt($cu, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, [
  'content-type' => 'application/json',
  'user-agent' => 'User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:122.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/122.0'
]);
curl_setopt($cu, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,true);
$json = curl_exec($cu);

//$json = file_get_contents($checkbtc);
//$json = utf8_encode($json);
$json_data = json_decode($json,true);
//print('<br>...'.$json_data.'...<br>');
var_dump($json_data);
```

Answer (score 1):

Check that here you are getting valid JSON string.

> $json = file_get_contents($checkbtc);

Remove this line. No need and is deprecated method as well.

> $json = utf8_encode($json);

From here tested and works.

```
$json = '{"success":true,"satoshi":"26.936"}';
$json_data = json_decode($json,true);
echo var_dump($json_data);
```

returns:

```
array(2) {
  ["success"]=>
  bool(true)
  ["satoshi"]=>
  string(6) "26.936"
}
```

[utf8_encode](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.utf8-encode.php) -- This function is **deprecated** as of PHP **8.2.0**.
Alternative: *mb_convert_encoding()*, which supports ISO-8859-1 and many other encodings.

Alternative way to get content from APi point:

- Use cURL when you need more control over the HTTP request, such as setting headers, handling different HTTP methods, or dealing with more complex scenarios like authentication or proxy servers.